# Allow multiple records to be returned through a WHERE clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an inventory table like:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------+
| inventory_id | film_id | available |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
|            1 |       1 | true      |
|            2 |       1 | false     |
|            3 |       1 | false     |
|            4 |       2 | false     |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

And a film table like:

```
+---------+--------+------+
| film_id | title  | cost |
+---------+--------+------+
|       1 | Title1 | 0.99 |
|       2 | Title2 | 1.99 |
+---------+--------+------+
```

My models and associations are correct and allowing me to access data across the two tables, but I'm attempting to sum the cost of each item in the inventory that has the available value: false.

My attempt is returning only a single copy of the film_id 1, although there are two records that match. What mistake am I making in how I am going about this?

Controller File:

```
def index
  @inventory = Inventory.where(available: false)
  @films = Film.where(film_id: @inventory.pluck(:film_id)
end
```

View:

```
<%= @films.sum(:cost).to_f %>
```

My current result is summing the column desired, but only including one instance of the film_id:1, instead of two instances.

Comment: The question is what are you trying to achieve? You current query returns all films that are currently available in one or more inventories. If you're trying to get the total cost of all films You're better of using `Film.all.sum(:cost)`. If you want to get the total value of items in inventory. 1) `film_id` `2` shouldn't come back since there is no film 2 available. 2) You're currently only selecting one of each movie available instead of the same amount as available.

Comment: Why would you expect 2 instances of the same Film object? there's only one film with ID 1, that's why it returns only one. I think you are mixing up your description, what you have are TWO INVENTORIES for that film, but there's only 1 film with that id.

Comment: You both bring up a miscommunication on my part. My goal is to return the cost for each item in the inventory that is not available, and then return a total sum of all the costs. So, I need there to be two instances of the film because there are two instances of the inventory that are not available. Hope that is clarifying. My temporary solution is below as an answer.

Comment: You can do this: `@films_not_in_available_inventory = Film.joins(:inventory).where(inventories: { available: false })` and then for the sum of all costs: `@films_not_in_available_inventory.sum(:cost)`

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji, that's a helpful solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by changing removing the Film.where clause, making my model:

```
def index
  @inventory = Inventory.where(available: false)
end
```

And changing my view to:

```
<% sum = 0 %>

<% @inventory.each do |i| %>
  <%= i.film.title %>
  <% cost = i.film.cost %>
  <% sum += cost.to_f %>
  <%= cost %>
<% end %>

<p>Total Sum:</p>
<%= sum %>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the best way to accomplish this task. If someone has a better or more efficient way, please share!

Comment: To make it more eficient, use `@inventory = Inventory.where(available: false).includes(:film)` to prevent N+1 queries https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes. The rest is ok, maybe you can refactor the code a little, but it won't be more performant.

Comment: Thanks arieljuod, that's helpful!